# ASP.Net WebForms not firing UI events from codebehind file

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have simple UI in aspx file, with aspx.cs codebehind. No matter what kind of control I use, events from this file wont fire - the only ones that are working are events like Init, PageLoad.
Events are created via designer.

What I tried:

1. Basic OnClick on markup page
2. OnClick in designer
3. Inline c# Code in markup page via javascript
4. PageMethods
5. Pure javascript click
6. Whole new page

When I add for example alert for click event in javascript, it works. But Im not able to run my c# code after user clicks on button.
I have also removed everything from file (validation, other controls...), but not even then my code works.
There are also no errors in console

**Markup Page**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master"  EnableEventValidation="false" CodeBehind="Report.aspx.cs" Async="true" Inherits="App.Web.Views.Besparingen.Report" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms" Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>

<asp:Content runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="Content" ID="Content1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('[id*=selectYear]').multiselect({
                includeSelectAllOption: true
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('[id*=selectPortfolio]').multiselect({
                includeSelectAllOption: true
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('[id*=selectSector]').multiselect({
                includeSelectAllOption: true
            });
        });
    </script>


    <form runat="server" id="form">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" ScriptMode="Release" ClientIDMode="Static" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
        </asp:ScriptManager>

        <div style="margin: 10px;">
            <asp:Label Style="margin-right: 40px;" ID="YearLabel" Text="Year:" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="selectYear"></asp:Label>
            <asp:ListBox ID="selectYear" runat="server" DataValueField="Value" DataTextField="Text" SelectionMode="Multiple" CausesValidation="false"></asp:ListBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ForeColor="Red"
                ControlToValidate="selectYear"
                ValidationGroup="yearGroup"
                ErrorMessage="Select year."
                runat="server">
            </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </div>
        <div style="margin: 10px;">
            <asp:Label Style="margin-right: 12px;" ID="PortfolioLabel" Text="Portfolio:" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="selectPortfolio"></asp:Label>
            <asp:ListBox ID="selectPortfolio" runat="server" DataValueField="Value" DataTextField="Text" CausesValidation="false"></asp:ListBox>
        </div>
        <div style="margin: 10px;">

            <asp:Label Style="margin-right: 25px;" ID="SectorLabel" Text="Sector:" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="selectSector"></asp:Label>
            <asp:ListBox ID="selectSector" runat="server" DataValueField="Value" DataTextField="Text" CausesValidation="false"></asp:ListBox>

        </div>
        <div>
            <asp:Button ID="reportButton" runat="server" OnClick="reportButton_Click" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="Create report" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="yearGroup" />
        </div>
        <div style="margin-top: 40px;">
            <rsweb:ReportViewer runat="server" ID="reporter" Width="100%" ClientIDMode="AutoID" ProcessingMode="Local" BackColor="White" BorderStyle="None" ToolBarItemBorderStyle="None" InternalBorderStyle="None" BorderColor="White" InternalBorderColor="White" ToolBarItemBorderColor="White" AsyncRendering="false"></rsweb:ReportViewer>
        </div>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //$("#reportButton").click(function () {
            //    event.preventDefault();
            //    alert("Handler for .click() called.");
            //});
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="Head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="Title" runat="server">
    Besparingen
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="ValidationSummary" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

**Code Behind file**

```
    public partial class Report : System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<model>
    {
        List<string> years = new List<string>();
        string sector;
        string portfolio;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                selectPortfolio.DataSource = Model.List[0].Portfolios;
                selectPortfolio.DataBind();
                selectYear.DataSource = Model.List[0].Years;
                selectYear.DataBind();
                selectSector.DataSource = Model.List[0].Sectors;
                selectSector.DataBind();
            }
        }

        protected void reportButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (ListItem item in selectYear.Items)
            {
                if (item.Selected)
                {
                    years.Add(item.Text);
                }
            }
            sector = selectSector.SelectedItem?.Text ?? string.Empty;
            portfolio = selectPortfolio.SelectedItem?.Text ?? string.Empty;

            if (years.Count > 0)
            {
                BesparingenDS.DataTable1DataTable table = new BesparingenDS.DataTable1DataTable();
                DataTable1TableAdapter adapter = new DataTable1TableAdapter();
                adapter.Fill(table, sector, portfolio, string.Join(",", years));
                ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource("DataSource", (DataTable)table);

                System.Security.PermissionSet sec = new System.Security.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.PermissionState.Unrestricted);

                reporter.LocalReport.SetBasePermissionsForSandboxAppDomain(sec);
                reporter.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Views\\Besparingen\\BesparingenReport.rdlc";
                reporter.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
                reporter.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);
                reporter.LocalReport.Refresh();
                reporter.DataBind();
            }
        }

    }
```

Thank you for help and sorry for my bad english

Comment: Your ASPX is webforms but your back end is MVC??? base page class of webforms is `System.Web.UI.Page`

Comment: I agree with above comment. There seems to be a mix of MCV and asp.net web forms. Something is VERY messed up. Perhaps a page was cut + pasted from MVC to asp.net webforms project? I would create a blank web form and try that. And then try create a blank web form (but include master). is this a MVC project, or a asp.net web forms application? So this mix of MVC and asp.net webforms has to be fixed.  What kind of project was created here?

Comment: You are right, I mixed webforms and MVC project. I got it finally running as intended, thank you!